# ant target to kill previous target

Tags: ant

I have an ant target to compile java classes and build war/ear in an application. But this build takes longer time ie almost 5 min  and need to wait till build completes. If i come to know ealier build is not correct, stop that build without manually killing and start new target after my new changes.

Now, I need another target which should stop the earlier build and start a new one. How can I do this? is this possible?

Comment: What causes your build to take 5 minutes? How are you learning that the build is invalid before it is finished? Are  you running tests that fail but still end up generating the WAR? If so, you should configure the testing task so that it fails if your tests don't pass.

Comment: application is very big having many projects to run. I have made some changes and started build, but came to know that something wrong and start fresh build for this i need to kill previous build manually which i dont want.

Comment: Sounds like you should break your application into multiple components and build them separately then.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution : If you are in unix machine then you can check if a similar process is running. If it is not then continue.